# Make sure MATLAB does not recalculate symbolic expression

Tags: matlab, optimization, symbolic-math, differential-equations

I am building (my first...) MatLab program, it needs to differentiate an equations symbolically and then use this solution many many times (with different numeric inputs).

I do not want it to recalculate the symbolic differentiation every time it needs to put in a new set of numeric values. This would probably greatly add to the time taken to run this program (which - given its nature, a numeric optimiser, will probably already be hours).

**My question is how can I structure my program such that it will not recalculate the symbolic differentiation?**

The class in question is:

```
function [ result ] = GradOmega(numX, numY, numZ, numMu)
syms x y z mu
omega = 0.5*(x^2+y^2+z^2) + (1-mu)/((x+mu)^2+y^2+z^2)^0.5 + mu/((x+mu-1)^2+y^2+z^2)^0.5;
symGradient = gradient(omega);
%//Substitute the given numeric values back into the funtion
result = subs(symGradient, {x,y,z,mu}, {numX, numY, numZ, numMu});
end
```

I know that I could just symbolically calculate the derivative and then copy-paste it into the code e.g.

```
gradX = x + ((2*mu + 2*x)*(mu - 1))/(2*((mu + x)^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2)) - (mu*(2*mu + 2*x - 2))/(2*((mu + x - 1)^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2));
gradY = y - (mu*y)/((mu + x - 1)^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2) + (y*(mu - 1))/((mu + x)^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2);
gradZ = z - (mu*z)/((mu + x - 1)^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2) + (z*(mu - 1))/((mu + x)^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2);
```

But then my code is a bit cryptic, which is a problem in a shared project. 
There is a related query here: http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/53542-oop-how-to-avoid-recalculation-on-dependent-properties-i-hope-a-mathwork-developer-could-give-me-a
But I'm afraid I couldn't follow the code. 
Also I am much more familiar with Java and Python, if that helps explain anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap your function into some kind of Function-Factory, which does not return numerical results, but a function that can be evaluated:

(I had to replace the call `syms` with `sym('mu')`, because for some reason it kept calling a `mutools` function in line `omega = ...`. I did also change the call to `gradient` to make sure the arguments are in correct order, and `mu` will be treated as constant.)

```
function GradOmega = GradOmegaFactory()
x = sym('x');
y = sym('y');
z = sym('z');
mu = sym('mu');
omega = 0.5*(x^2+y^2+z^2) + (1-mu)/((x+mu)^2+y^2+z^2)^0.5 + mu/((x+mu-1)^2+y^2+z^2)^0.5;
symGradient = gradient(omega,{'x','y','z'});
GradOmega = matlabFunction(symGradient, 'vars', {'x','y','z','mu'});
end
```

Then you would call it via:

```
GradOmega = GradOmegaFactory();
result1 = GradOmega(numX1, numY1, numZ1, numMu1);
result2 = GradOmega(numX2, numY2, numZ2, numMu2);
result3 = GradOmega(numX3, numY3, numZ3, numMu3);
...
```

### Even better:

You could go even more fancy and use a wrapper function `GradOmega` which builds such a function inside and makes it `persistent`, to get the same interface you had with your initial approach. The first time you call the function `GradOmega` the symbolic expression is evaluated, but on each consecutive call you will only have to evaluate the generated function handle, which means it should be nearly as fast as if you hard-coded it.

```
function result = GradOmega(numX, numY, numZ, numMu)
persistent numericalGradOmega;
if isempty(numericalGradOmega)
    numericalGradOmega = GradOmegaFactory();
end
result = numericalGradOmega(numX, numY, numZ, numMu);
end
```

Use this like you would use your original version

```
result = GradOmega(numX, numY, numZ, numMu);
```

Just copy and paste both functions into a single `GradOmega.m` file. (`GradOmega` should be the first function in the file.)

---

Another tip: You can even evaluate this function using vectors. Instead of calling `GradOmega(1,2,3,4)` and `GradOmega(5,6,7,8)` afterwards, you can save the time overhead via the call `GradOmega([1,5], [2,6], [3,7], [4,8])` using row vectors.

Yet another tip: To clean up your code even more, you could also put the first lines into a separate `symOmega.m` file.

```
function omega = symOmega()
x = sym('x');
y = sym('y');
z = sym('z');
mu = sym('mu');
omega = 0.5*(x^2+y^2+z^2) + (1-mu)/((x+mu)^2+y^2+z^2)^0.5 + mu/((x+mu-1)^2+y^2+z^2)^0.5;
```

This way you don't have to have a copy of this symbolic expression in every file you use it. This can be beneficial if you also want to evaluate `Omega` itself, as you then can make use of the same Factory-approach listed in this answer. You would end up with the following files: `symOmega.m`, `Omega.m` and `GradOmega.m`, where only the file `symOmega.m` has the actual mathematical formula and the other two files make use of `symOmega.m`.