# Matlab - dynamically produce string for anonymous function

Tags: string, matlab

I am trying to produce the argument string for an anonymous function based on the number of input arguments *without using for loops*. For example, if N=3, then I want a string that reads

```
@(ax(1),ax(2),ax(3),ay(1),ay(2),ay(3))
```

I tried using repmat('ax',1,N) but I cannot figure out how to interleave the (i) index.

Any ideas?

---

Aside: Great answers so far, the above problem has been solved. To provide some intuition for those who are wondering *why* I want to do this: I need to construct a very large matrix anonymous function (a Jacobian) on the order of 3000x3000. I initially used the Matlab operations jacobian and matlabFunction to construct the anonymous function; however, this was quite slow. Instead, since the closed form of the derivative was quite simple, I decided to form the anonymous function directly. This was done by forming the symbolic Jacobian matrix, J, then appending it to the above @() string by using char(J{:})' and using eval to form the final anonymous function. This may not be the most elegant solution but I find it runs much faster than the jacobian/matlabFunction combination, especially for large N (additionally the structure of the new approach allows for the evaluation to be done in parallel).

EDIT: Just for completeness, the correct form of the argument string for the anonymous function should read

```
@(ax1,ax2,ax3,ay1,ay2,ay3)
```

to avoid a syntax error associated with indexing.

Comment: Using a string to do this is not a great solution. I suspect you might want to use `varargin` instead. Which anonymous functions do you want to build exactly? Second of all: The syntax you are creating there is not valid in MATLAB.

Comment: In anticipation of my Mentalist badge I predict that the OP really wants something like this: `f = @(ax, ay) ...`, which will then be called via `f([a,b,c],[d,e,f])`

Comment: Thank you for trying to clarify. I still don't get how the answers solve your problem. They just produce a syntax error if you use `str2func` on them.

Comment: In the spirit of building a fast function from a symbolic derivative I suggest to use the concept from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525890/make-sure-matlab-does-not-recalculate-symbolic-expression/28526108#28526108). It makes for beautiful code and is as fast as if you were to build the function by hand.

Comment: You may want to post a question with your actual function to differentiate. The string and `eval` approach is something neither beautiful nor fast. (And I still don't get how the solutions achieve anything but a syntax error)

Comment: @knedlsepp Minor modification of the indexing, I am using ax1, ax2, ax3, ... in the anonymous function, constructed via sym('ax',[N 1]), not (mistakenly) the indexing in the original question!

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: @knedlsepp The purpose of the question was just to generate the desired string, of which the accepted answer does efficiently. I don't reach the syntax error that you are describing :-)

Comment: Well, you can generate the string for sure. But you can't use this string for anything else like `eval` or `str2func` ..., as it is incorrect matlab-syntax. Still I think there is a much better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
N = 3;
argumentString = [repmat('ax(%i),',1,N),repmat('ay(%i),',1,N)];

functionString = sprintf(['@(',argumentString(1:end-1),')'], 1:N, 1:N)
```

First, you create input masks for sprintf (e.g. `'ax(%i)'`), which you then fill in with the appropriate numbers to create the function string.

Note: the syntax `@(ax(1),...)` will not actually work. More likely, you want to use either `@()someFunction(ax(1),...)`, or you are trying to pass multiple input arguments to an existing function, in which case storing the inputs in a cell array and calling the function as `fun(axCell{:})` would work.

Comment: I don't get all the answers. What the OP wants there doesn't make any sense!?

Comment: Hi, thank you. Yes I plan to append the function (in string form) to the above then use eval() to obtain my anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
N = 3;
sx = strcat('ax(', arrayfun(@num2str, 1:N, 'uniformoutput', 0), '),');
sy = strcat('ay(', arrayfun(@num2str, 1:N, 'uniformoutput', 0), '),');
str = [sx{:} sy{:}];
str = ['@(' str(1:end-1) ')']
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Can I ask you what the second set of square brackets do in the str definition?

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, but I find that this produces an incorrect output when N>9.

Comment: @Erik Those brackets were not needed. I have corrected that, and also it now works for N>9

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to use `arrayfun`:

```
sx = strjoin(arrayfun(@(x) ['ax(' num2str(x) ')'], 1:3, 'UniformOutput', false), ',');
sy = strjoin(arrayfun(@(x) ['ay(' num2str(x) ')'], 1:3, 'UniformOutput', false), ',');
s = ['@(' sx ',' sy ')'];
```

contains

```
'@(ax(1),ax(2),ax(3),ay(1),ay(2),ay(3))'
```

Best,

Comment: Hi, thanks! Unfortunately, I do not have strjoin in my Matlab version. Is this a recent function addition? Any way to replicate it using other functions?

Comment: Oh yeah, it appeared in R2014b I think. I'm using R2015a. You have this [equivalent](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21710-string-toolkits/content/strings/strjoin.m) on Matlab Central or you can use `sprintf`as described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/20043-function-for-concatenating-strings-with-delimiters).