# How to use symbolic-math of Matlab to obtain Gradient of a complex equation

Tags: matlab, optimization, gradient, symbolic-math, differential-equations

I am solving a hug optimization problem that takes a lot of time to converge to a solution. This is for the reason that Matlab uses finite difference method for calculating the Gradient of objective functions and nonlinear constraint and also constructing Hessian matrix. But there is an option in `fmincon` solver that allow you to supply the analytic derivative of functions and constraints.

For this reason I wanted to know how can I calculate the Grad of the namely function which is given here both in `mathematical` aspect and `symbolic math` tool.   I should note that still I want the gradient of the objective in the vector format.  (not by extracting `Eq1` in 5 equation.)
**Lets assume we have these optimization variables**

```
Pd=[x1 x2 x3 x4]
```

**Now we define these 2 variables based on optimization vector i.e.,`Pd`**

```
Pdn=[pd(1);mo;Pd(2);0;Pd(4)]
Pgn=[pd(2);Pd(1);m1;Pd(4),Pd(1)]
```

Now this is the equation that I want to take the gradient from:

```
Eq1=Sin(Pdn)+Pdn+Pgn.^2
```

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28525890/make-sure-matlab-does-not-recalculate-symbolic-expression/

Comment: It seems very complex to me. I need some hints @knedlsepp

Comment: It seems this question is quite different from your link. He is mostly asking about optimization vector manipulation which is interesting. @knedlsepp

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to supply the analytic gradient to `fmincon`? Or, rather, what is insufficient about the current solutions you obtain?

Comment: Because my optimization problem contains `405` decision variables and `300` constraints (it is 8 if I vectorize the nonlinear constraints). I checked Matlab profile and realized that 70% of optimization time is consumed by `finitedifference` function of Matlab. As I searched and asked from experts, they all were agreed that supply the grad and hessian will drastically reduce the computation time.  @horchler

Comment: I edited and simplified my question. Please check my updates. @knedlsepp

Comment: Dear Jamais, there are dozens of possible efficient ways for doing this optimization from the command prompt with built in functions. Do you wish to use any in particular?. By the way, which is the form of your objective function and restrictions? -i.e. the specific form of the Pd vector|function-. Indeed if there is a analytic function, of course you have to provide gradients, if there is not a closed form!!

Comment: Please a brief|link for the problem would be useful, for helping you to select the best way to solve the problem efficiently..... More, if the problem is huge!